# Trouble with $gt in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've successfully queried what I'm trying to in the mongo CLI, with the following query.

```
db.catches.find({'weightTotal': {'$gte' : 150} })
```

However, when I try to send a query up from angular to the route as such (with a little more specificity):

```
Hatchery.getByLocation(
        {
            'x': $scope.y.x._id,
            'city': place.data[0].city,
            'weightTotal': {'$gte' : 150 }
        })
```

I get the usual error when something blows up in mongoose:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'toString' of undefined
at ServerResponse.writeHead (http.js:1180:45)
at ServerResponse.writeHead (/Users/ShiftedRec/x/y/node_modules/express-session/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:53:19)
```

But more specifically (console logging the error)

```
{ message: 'Cast to number failed for value "{"$gte":150}" at path "weightTotal"',
 name: 'CastError',
 kind: 'number',
 value: '{"$gte":150}',
 path: 'weightTotal' }
```

I've gotten this to work by doing a `.where` in the route, but I'd rather fit everything in the query.  It can keep my routes cleaner if I just pass what I need to into a query instead of doing conditional where statements based on permissions etc.

The route the query is passed to looks like this:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
User
    .find(req.query)
    .populate('post')
    .exec(function (err, data){
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

req.query console logs into this:

```
{ x: '5581efdcc465c1ccd97a1f6b',
  y: '5581efe2458256f5d9848ca7',
  weightTotal: '{"$gt": 150}' }
```

I'm using Mongoose 4.0.1.
Any ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell without node.js code responsible for querying database.

Comment: More code could help

Comment: Apologies, added the route that does the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests queries are strings, so if you send this:

```
www.mysite.com/?data=1&weightTotal=5
```

You will get this (strings and not numbers):

```
{data: "1",
 weightTotal: "5"}
```

In order to use the data you can parse it somehow, for example:

```
req.query.weightTotal = JSON.parse(req.query.weightTotal);
```

or if it's just a number, a faster parse is:

```
req.query.weightTotal = +req.query.weightTotal;
```

A smarter solution, if you are sending objects in your requests, will be to use POST and not GET.

Comment: JSON.parse was exactly what I needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the `req.query.weightTotal` string to an object first:

```
req.query.weightTotal = eval('(' + req.query.weightTotal + ')');
```

Check the demo below.

```js
var obj = { 
    x: '5581efdcc465c1ccd97a1f6b',
    y: '5581efe2458256f5d9848ca7',
    weightTotal: '{"$gt": 150}' 
}
obj.weightTotal = eval('(' + obj.weightTotal + ')');

pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>
```

Comment: Of course, because I was sending an object through an http request, it gets converted into a string, right?  I suppose it would be prudent to loop through each key run that line of code on it.  Would you agree?

Comment: Is there a way to pass up the object without the weightTotal value being converted toa  string?  the top level object isn't a string when it arrives, but the inner one is. Why is that?

Comment: @Peege151 Should be doable, refer to this [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19379587/) for more detail.